# Make li active for bootstrap nav navbar-nav

Tags: javascript

```
<!-- BEGIN HEADER MENU -->
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown dropdown-fw dropdown-fw-disabled active open selected">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="text-uppercase">
                            <i class="icon-home"></i> Home </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-fw">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="{{ url('/externalphotoviewer') }}">
                                    <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i> View Photo </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ url('about') }}">
                                    <i class="icon-bulb"></i> About </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ url('contact') }}">
                                    <i class="icon-graph"></i> Contact </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown dropdown-fw dropdown-fw-disabled ">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="text-uppercase">
                            <i class="icon-home"></i> Upload </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-fw">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="{{ url('picture/create') }}">
                                    <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i> Upload Photo </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ url('about') }}">
                                    <i class="icon-bulb"></i> View Photo List </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- END HEADER MENU -->
```

Im trying to make the selected li tag active whenever a user click on it. It should be selected as the active tag. I tried the below code but it doesnt work. I am still very new to javascript. please help thank you

```
<script>
            $(".li").on("click", function(){
           $(".li").find(".active").removeClass("active");
           $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Add a working example

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code**

`li` is element selector not a class selector

```
 $(".dropdown-menu-fw li").on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();//Remove this line to route to links
   e.stopPropagation();
   $(this).parents('.open').find("li").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
  });
```

```js
 $(".dropdown-menu-fw li").on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();//Remove this line to route to links
   e.stopPropagation();
   $(this).parents('.open').find("li").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
  });
  
$(".dropdown-fw").on("click",function(){
  $(".dropdown-fw").removeClass("open selected");
  $(this).addClass("open selected");
})
```

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css');
.collapse {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown dropdown-fw dropdown-fw-disabled active open selected">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="text-uppercase">
                            <i class="icon-home"></i> Home </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-fw">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="{{ url('/externalphotoviewer') }}">
                                    <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i> View Photo </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ url('about') }}">
                                    <i class="icon-bulb"></i> About </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ url('contact') }}">
                                    <i class="icon-graph"></i> Contact </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown dropdown-fw dropdown-fw-disabled ">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="text-uppercase">
                            <i class="icon-home"></i> Upload </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-fw">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="{{ url('picture/create') }}">
                                    <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i> Upload Photo </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ url('about') }}">
                                    <i class="icon-bulb"></i> View Photo List </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. It is making the tags active when i click it. However, it suddenly doesn't route to the links that the tabs should lead to. How do i fix this? thanks

Comment: just remove `e.preventDefault();` from above code.Its preventing links from routing

Comment: I removed e.preventDefault() as you suggested. But then it goes back to the  same behaviour it was before and does not work again. Can you try putting external test links in your code and see if you get the same issues? thanks

Comment: see this https://plnkr.co/edit/DYhz32MGdYe2RDuHEymt?p=preview .check clicking on `click Here` menu